# Why assignment operator working even when it was forbidden?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I'm struggling with OOP again. I tried to implement signgly linked list, here's the code:

```
template <typename T>
class node
{
    T value;
    node* next;

public:
    node(const T& n)
    {
        this->value = n;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
    ~node()
    {
        //is it ok to leave destructor empty in my case?
    }
};

template <typename T>
class list
{
    node<T>* head;
    node<T>* tail;

public:
    list()
    {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
    }
    list(const list& arr)
    {
        *this = list(); //<================== the line I mentioned
        node* current_this = this->head;
        node* current_arr = this->arr;
        while (current_arr != nullptr)
        {
            current_this = new node(current_arr);
            current_arr = current_arr->next;
            current_this = current_this->next;
        }
    }
    list(list&& arr)
    {
        this->head = arr.head;
        this->tail = arr.tail;
        arr = list(); //<================== the line I mentioned
    }
    ~list()
    {
        node* current = this->head;
        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            node* next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
    }
};
```

I wrote some lines without thinking, i.e. `arr = list()` and `*this = list()`. I didn't implemented `operator=` so there should be some troubles. I thought compiler has decided to generate copy/move assigment for me, so I decided to add these lines, just for curiosity sake:

```
list& operator=(const list& arr) = delete;
list& operator=(list&& arr) = delete;
```

But it still compiled and I don't understand why. What's the deal here? Shoudn't assignment be forbidden and therefore `arr = list()` and `*this = list()` be illegal?

Comment: Related, I *think* you're intending on using a *delegating constructor* to initialize `head` and `tail`, but just have it in the wrong place. If you put `: list()` as the base+member initializer list of both of those ctors, you'll get what you want without the incorrect vernacular (though you should/better do proper swaps rather than assignments in your move ctor for the members).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates aren't evaluated unless/until you instantiate them. If you don't use the copy or move constructor, then their bugs don't produce errors.

Comment: Indeed, I was not aware of that. And I have a lot of different errors in my code. I need some time to fix them

Comment: Yep, I got that error. You are right.